# Configuration file for Python

Tags: python, list, file, configuration

Is there any standard for python configuration files? What I would like to have is a seperate document to my script which would have the options of my script in it. For example...

```
Test Options
Random_AOI      = 1
Random_ReadMode = 1
```

These would then become a list within the python script, such as...

```
test_options(random_aoi, random_readmode)
```

Would I have to use regular expressions and scan the document or is there an easier way of performing this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there's [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), which parses .ini files.

There's a handy introduction to it [here](http://pymotw.com/2/ConfigParser/).

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" config file formats for Python are INI (which you parse/write with the `ConfigParser` module -- http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) and JSON (http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).